# Firefox Driver fails with org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am getting this exception when running tests in Firefox.

```
    com.codeborne.selenide.ex.SoftAssertionError: Test DraftTest.setUp failed (3 failures)
        org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
        org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
        org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    
        at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.ErrorsCollector.cleanAndGetAssertionError(ErrorsCollector.java:64)
        at com.codeborne.selenide.testng.SoftAsserts.failIfErrors(SoftAsserts.java:91)
        at com.codeborne.selenide.testng.SoftAsserts.onConfigurationFailure(SoftAsserts.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
        at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Firefox version: 98.0.1

Selenide version: 6.3.4 (Selenium 4.1.2)

Comment: Check the browser version and the driver version you are using. Download the compatible Firefox driver for your version and give a try

Comment: @dheeraj In Selenide, WebDriverManager is always seeking and downloading drivers during test execution.

Comment: Can you check manually whether the webdriver manager is downloading the correct driver compatible to your firefox? Else need to update your Firefox or way to download the driver matching your firefox version

Comment: @dheeraj I manually set geckodriver and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error running my tests using Selenium `4.3.0` and Firefox `91.6`. I downloaded the latest geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (`0.31.0` at the time of this writing) and that resolved the issue for me.